# Change the table to dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table which will be loaded dynamically using jQuery.

I would like to change this into DataTable for better view and scroll/pagination.

Since I am new, I am not sure about correct procedure to get the expected data.

So it would be much appreciated if someone guide me on how to change my below code to DataTable and also scroll/pagination tips.

And also major doubt is, whether we can map user editable table into DataTable?

```js
//get item list from erp tables
$.post('geterpitem', {
    grn: $('#num').val()
}, function(responseJson) {
    if (responseJson.length != null) {
        var $tbl = $("#itemtable");
        $tbody = $tbl.find('tbody');
        $tbl.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var i = 1;
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
            rowNew.children().eq(0).append(i);
            rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemcode']);
            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemname']);
            rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['receivedqty']);
            rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text"  id="inspdate"/>');
            rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text"  id="accep" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>');
            rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text"  id="rejec"/>');
            rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text"  id="rema"/>');
            rowNew.appendTo($tbody);
            i++;
        });
    } else {
        alert("No item found!!");
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemtable').DataTable()
});
```

```html
<table border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="itemtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SLno</th>
            <th>Item code</th>
            <th>Item name</th>
            <th>Received qty</th>
            <th>Insp Date</th>
            <th>Accepted qty</th>
            <th>Rejected qty</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where does DataTable() come from ?

Comment: Which type of datatable you are trying, server side or client side? And where is the related code?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: i am trying populate client side table with some table data dynamically. there are some <td> will be edited by user also. Come to know that datatable have more features. so i am trying use those

Answer (score 0):

you are manually creating the table when datatables can do all that for you.
below is untested but its how I would do it based on your code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post('geterpitem', {
            grn: $('#num').val()
        }, function (responseJson) {
            if (responseJson.length != null) {
                defineTable(responseJson);
            } else {
                $('#itemtable').DataTable();
                alert("No item found!!");
            }
        });
    });
    function defineTable(jsonData){
        var lineNum = 1;
        $('#itemtable').DataTable({
            data: jsonData, 
            columnDefs:[{ targets: [4,5,6,7], render: function () { return "<input type='text' />";} }],
            columns: [
                { data: function () {return lineNum++;}},
                { data: "itemcode" },
                { data: "itemname" },
                { data: "receivedqty" },
                { data: null },
                { data: null, className:"aNumber" },
                { data: null },
                { data: null },
                 ]
        });
        $('#itemtable .aNumber').on("keypress", "input", function (evt) { isNumber(evt);})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert any html table to datatable follow these simple steps :

Add advanced interaction controls to your HTML tables simply using three libraries as following:

1. CSS
2. jQuery Library
3. DataTable JS Library

Add under head section

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com//ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Add before closing body (`</body>`)

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#tableId').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```